# is `retry` a C keyword

Tags: c, freebsd

I'am not a kick-ass C developer and just was curious about FreeBSD kernel. When I was reading some files, found [**This line**](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/kern/kern_fork.c#L260). I googled for it and found nothing. Is it a C keyword? Is it simply a mistake and should be commented?

Comment: It's a label.  It can be used as the target of a `goto` statement.  People generally try to avoid them, but they are a part of the language.

Comment: That is a label. This line goes back to that label: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/kern/kern_fork.c#L281 (there could be more, I just looked for one) - A line that consists of an identifier and a colon, and that isn't inside a comment or string, is such a label.

Answer (score 3):

You’re looking at an example of C’s goto functionality.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/goto-statement-in-c-cpp/

Dijkstra wrote a famous paper titled “Go To Statement Considered Harmful,” and now goto statements are rarely used.

Comment: ..except to exit nested loops and for error handling (as C has no structured error handling).

Comment: Can't mention that paper without also bringing up Knuth's response, [Structured Programming With goto Statements](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~mak/CS185C/KnuthStructuredProgrammingGoTo.pdf). (It's a fascinating look into the origins of many control flow constructs commonly seen today, and argues that blanket statements like "don't use goto" are bad )